# I want to move 3 worksheets from one workbook to another workbook. i tried many macros but currently using this one

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

```
 `Sub MovetoNewSheet()
 Dim ObjWb As Workbook
 Dim ObjWs As Worksheet
 Set ObjWb = Workbooks("CompareResults.xlsx")
 Set ObjWs = Worksheets("Sheet3")
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result").Move Before:=ObjWb.ObjWs
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DeletedBlocks").Move Before:=ObjWb.ObjWs
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("COUNT").Move Before:=ObjWb.ObjWs
End Sub
```

i am using the above code to move 3 sheets from one workbook to another.
 the CompareResult sheet is open, please help me out.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Hi @YashPisat, what was your issue? You don't state very well your issue?

Comment: i get an error stating "Object or method not properly defined" So can anyone help with a macro for moving 3 worksheet from one workbook to another